# In pandas when querying, how to skip filters that are None?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I skip (don't apply) the filters that are None?

```
res = df[
  (df['Column1'] >= column1_min) & (df_item['Column1'] <= column1_max) &
  (df['Column2'].isin(column2) ) &
  (df['Column3'] == column3) &
  #.....
```

that is, if `column1_min` or `column1_max` or `column2` or `column3` are `None`, then don't filter on them. Here they're all applied in any case. If any of them is `None`, it'll search for `None` values which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you can try this:

```
res = df[( (df['Column1'] >= column1_min) if column1_min != None else True) &
         ( (df['Column1'] <= column1_max) if column1_max != None else True) &
         ( (df['Column2'].isin(column2) ) if column2 != None else True ) &
         ( (df['Column3'] == column3    ) if column3 != None else True)]
```

It's a bit long, but should work as expected.

The condition is evaluated if the value is not `None`. If it is `None`, the condition is `True`, which won't affect the query.